# Overload de operador com erro

Tags: c, c++

O código abaixo está com o seguinte erro:

Erro:

```
[Error] invalid operands of types 'Ponteiro*' and 'Ponteiro*' to binary 'operator+'
```

Código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Ponteiro{
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        void valores(int _x = 0, int _y = 0);   
        int soma();
        void operator + (Ponteiro* p);
};

void Ponteiro::valores(int _x, int _y){
    this->x = _x;
    this->y = _y;
}

int Ponteiro::soma(){
    return this->x + this->y; 
}

void Ponteiro::operator +(Ponteiro* p){
    this->x += p->x;
    this->y += p->y;
}

int main() {
    
    Ponteiro* pt = new Ponteiro();
    pt->valores(1,2);
    
    Ponteiro* pt2 = new Ponteiro();
    pt2->valores(3, 4);

    pt = pt + pt2;
            
}
```

Por que o overload não funciona? é conflito com o ponteiro?

Answer (score 4):

Você tem uma boa explicação acima, mas vou te mostrar um outro exemplo, talvez mais completo.

Sua classe se chamar `Ponteiro` provavelmente não foi a melhor opção. Considerando que ela tem dois `int` `x` e `y` talvez pudesse usar para representar um `Ponto` mesmo, como a clássica estrutura (C)

```
typedef struct _COORD {
  SHORT X;
  SHORT Y;
} COORD, *PCOORD;
```

usada pelo Windows para endereçar pixels, onde `x` é a coluna e `y` a linha.

**O que é `valores()`?**

```
    void Ponto::valores(int _x, int _y)
    {
        this->x = _x;
        this->y = _y;
    }
```

Isso é apenas um possível construtor da classe. Não deve criar uma função. Faça o simples:

```
   Ponto::Ponto(int _x, int _y)
   {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
   }
```

Que normalmente é escrito assim:

```
    Ponto::Ponto(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {};
```

porque é mais simples e fácil de ler. E defina sempre o construtor padrão, o que não tem argumentos. No exemplo abaixo vou fazer o simples e deixar o padrão como `(0,0)`.

E não precisa escrever esses `this` toda hora. C++ não é java

**O que é `soma()`?**

```
    int Ponto::soma() { return this->x + this->y; }
```

Note que pode escrever assim numa linha só quando achar legível.

No entanto imagino que seja isso que quer transformar no `operator+`

E aí tem um problema (talvez). Muito da vantagem em redefinir um operador assim é poder operar com eles como numa expressão, do mesmo modo que faz com

```
    int a = 42;
    int b = 600;
    int c = a + b;
```

poder escrever

```
    Ponto a(10,10);
    Ponto b(1, 2);
 
    Ponto c = a + b;
```

e ter `c.x` = 11 e `c.y` = 12
e poder usar expressões como `a + b + c + d` onde tem 4 `Ponto`.

Para fazer isso deve entender o polimorfismo e o fato de que `+` vai representar uma soma afinal. E a `+ b` deve retornar o que? Não um `int`, mas um novo `Ponto`. Claro, pode ter as 2 coisas. Isso é polimorfismo. Mas o relevante é ter a soma de dois `Ponto` gerando um `Ponto`.

E deve usar referências, não ponteiros. E claro que a soma não altera as parcelas então deve declarar as parcelas `const&` assim

```
Ponto operator+ (const Ponto& A, const Ponto& B)
{
    return Ponto(A.x + B.x, A.y + B.y);
}
```

E entenda que operator+ não faz parte da classe, pode ser uma *free function*

#### Overloading <<

Uma comodidade comum seria redefinir o shift a esquerda --- `<<` --- para um `Ponto`, como é comum redefinir `toString()` em java e vou deixar aqui um exemplo porque acho que faz sentido. Assim pode usar `cout << ponto` e ter controle centralizado sobre o que vai mostrar na tela. Assim esse código em `main()`

```
    Ponto A = Ponto(-3,-4); 
    cout << A << endl;

    Ponto B = Ponto(2, 3);
    cout << A << " + " << B << " = " << A + B << endl;

    Ponto P = Ponto(); // vai ser criado (0,0)
    cout << "Padrao: " << P << endl;
```

mostra

```
(-3,-4)
(-3,-4) + (2,3) = (-1,-1)
Padrao: (0,0)
```

E acho que dá pra ver que é bem legível. Claro que normalmente seria preciso implementar mais um monte de operadores, mas a idéia é a mesma sempre.

O exemplo tem uma classe `Ponto` e um arquivo `main.cpp`

#### Ponto.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Ponto
{
public:
    int x; // coluna
    int y;

public:
    Ponto(int, int);
    Ponto(); // construtor padrao

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Ponto&);
    friend Ponto operator+ (const Ponto& A, const Ponto& B);
};
```

#### Ponto.cpp

```
#include "Ponto.h"

Ponto::Ponto(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {};
Ponto::Ponto() : Ponto(0,0) {}; // padrao

ostream& operator<< (ostream& fluxo, const Ponto& p)
{
    fluxo << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
    return fluxo;
}

Ponto operator+ (const Ponto& A, const Ponto& B)
{
    return Ponto(A.x + B.x, A.y + B.y);
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ponto.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    Ponto A = Ponto(-3,-4); 
    cout << A << endl;

    Ponto B = Ponto(2, 3);
    cout << A << " + " << B << " = " << A + B << endl;

    Ponto P = Ponto(); // vai ser criado (0,0)
    cout << "Padrao: " << P << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note que normalmente `x` e `y` seriam definidos como `private` Declarando assim, código que use a classe não tem acesso aos campos de `Ponto`: apenas através de funções da classe. Esse é o conceito de **encapsulamento**. Por isso declarei as funções que implementam os operadores como `friend`, como exemplo do que precisaria fazer. Com os campos `x` e `y` declarados `public` não há necessidade de usar `friend`: Todos são amigos :)

Comment: Obrigado cara, você me ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 1):

Esse padrão que você adotou para o *overload* do ponteiro ficou um pouco confuso.

O método foi implementado para a classe `Ponteiro`, o que significa que você só pode utiliza-lo para uma instancia de `Ponteiro`, mas no seu código você está tentando utiliza-lo para uma instancia de `Ponteiro*`, o que não é a mesma coisa.

Então o valor que dever ser recebido à direita do operador é um `Ponteiro*`, ou seja, esse *overload* só consegue somar tipos `Ponteiro` com `Ponteiro*`.

Para utilizar a sua implementação, primeiro você precisaria de-referenciar `pt` e soma-lo com `pt2`:

```
(*pt) + pt2;
```

Detalhe que o retorno dessa operação é `void`, então você não pode atribuir o resultado para `pt`. O fato do operador estar mutando o valor de `pt` ao invés de retornar um valor novo também é um padrão estranho.

Tradicionalmente o *overload* do `+` é feito recebendo uma estrutura (não um ponteiro) e retornando uma estrutura do mesmo tipo:

```
Ponteiro Ponteiro::operator +(Ponteiro p) {
    return Ponteiro {
        .x = this->x + p.x,
        .y = this->y + p.y,
    };
}
```

Dessa forma sim faria sentido escrever o código da maneira que você fez na pergunta... exceto pelo ponto de que você deveria estar declarando essas estruturas na pilha, ao invés da aloca-las no *heap* com o operador `new`:

```
int main() {
    
    Ponteiro pt;
    pt.valores(1,2);
    
    Ponteiro pt2;
    pt2.valores(3, 4);

    pt = pt + pt2;
    cout << pt.x << "\n";
    cout << pt.y << endl;

}
```

Em nota: nada nesse código é de fato um ponteiro, então talvez faça sentido dar outro nome para a sua estrutura `Ponteiro`.

Comment: Entendi cara, muito obrigado!